# Library to infer field-delimited file information

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I have various "unknown" field-separated files that are being uploaded by users (I have zero control or even knowledge of what they will be other then that they will end in "v"), and I would like to see if there are existing libraries (hopefully in python) that infer the following information about an unknown field-separated file:

- What line number the header is on.
- Whether there is a header or not.
- What the separator is.
- If any rows are skipped after the header

[image]

In the above example, the header would start one line 2, and the data would start on line 4 (the separator here is a tab, but that's not shown in the grid above).

Are there any open-source libraries (ML/AI?) that try to infer file heading information based on the first ~100 lines of data or so? Here's one approach from a Google search, but doesn't specify any software packages: https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/hpcc/2016/4297/00/07828554.pdf.

---

**Update**: essentially, I'm looking if a library exists (in any language) where I could pass it **ONLY THE FIRST 100 ROWS OF DATA** and it would be able to make an educated guess on (1) what line the header is on (2) what line the data starts at; and (3) what the delimiter is.

Comment: Hi, given your level of reputation, you surely know that this kind of question is off-topic, because you are asking for a library recommendation, and you don't have a programming issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). It is the go-to library for data parsing/analysis today.

The CSV parser supports auto-detection of separators, as well as you can provide patterns to specify comments. For example '#' in the above case.

I'm yet not sure how it will behave due to the first line above, as it is not starting with a comment character, I will improve the answer if I find out more information.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This may be a silly question as I haven't used that library before in any non-trivial way, but does it support other file types as well, such as xml or json or xls(x)?

Comment: @David542 It supports almost every common types. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#input-output

Answer (score 0):

In java you can parse xls and csv files using

apache-poi: https://poi.apache.org/

apache-commons-csv: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

It's useless to say that these are excellent libraries and you have a lot of features.

I will try to give my contribution for the other features you are searching. (some could be obvious)

> What line number the header is on

You start to read all lines when you find the first line with values it should be the header and you know in which line you are

> Whether there is a header or not

Unless you have a specific requirements, I don't think it's possible to say this could be feasible. Let's say for example you have a very generic string as header and as value too. You need some nlp library too.

> What the separator is

You can count all separators in the first 20 or 30 lines of values (probably 5 is sufficient) and see if one is present and which

> If any rows are skipped after the header

Both these libraries doesn't stop unless they reach the end of file. So if a line is empty, you will know and you can continue to parse the next one.